# Are questions about AI/DS API prices on-topic or off-topic on this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

Here is an example of a question about AI/DS API prices:

> Question about Azure OpenAI pricing: Assume I ran 2 queries on GPT-4 (8k-token context). Each query consisted of 8 prompt tokens. Each query returned 2 completion tokens. Let's assume I don't use any special price discount. Does that cost 0.03 + 0.06 USD, or (0.03 + 0.06) * 2 USD? I looked at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/ and  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/openai-service/  but couldn't find the information.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider this off-topic, since this is about the price of a service rather than about its implementation/use/... . But since `azure-ml` etc. is generally on-topic I would still accept it for simplicity's sake (unless we would get all of sudden overrun by pricing questions).